# Fotorama Transition Duration

Tags: fotorama

Does anybody know how to change Transition Duration for the Fotorama jquery Plugin?

(4.1.17  http://fotorama.io)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is posible since 4.2.3.

Set animation length in milliseconds using `data-transition-duration`:

```
<div class="fotorama" data-transition-duration="1000">
  <a href="1.jpg"></a>
  <a href="2.jpg"></a>
  <a href="3.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

To see the changes, click on the stage or navigation. This option does not affect the behavior of the swipe.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/artpolikarpov/jrCC5/embedded/result,html,js/

Answer (score 0):

You can use following  attributes in   js section

```
transitionDuration: 333
```

You can find the more  detail on this

[jsffidle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/artpolikarpov/BJRHU/)